# Can't get arrays to work in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

So I'm having a problem with my code here:

```
$answerString = $_GET['answers'];

$questionsString = $_GET['questions'];

$question = array();

$answer = explode(',', $answerString);

$question = explode(',', $questionsString);

$score = 0;

for($index = 0; $index <= 9; $index++)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id = '$question[$index]'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    $cans = $rows['answer'];
    $test = array($cans);
    $ans = array();
    foreach ($test as $correct){
    $ans[] = $correct;
    }
    print_r($ans);

            if($answer[$index] == $rows['answer'])
    {
        $score++;
    }

}
```

What I want to do with it, is to store each $cans into an array having elements and such, but this code will output all data into element 0 and so I can't call them all to use in a variable.

```
Array ( [0] => C ) Array ( [0] => C ) Array ( [0] => D ) Array ( [0] => A ) Array ( [0] => B ) Array ( [0] => B ) Array ( [0] => A ) Array ( [0] => C ) Array ( [0] => B ) Array ( [0] => D )
```

then if I replaced these codes

```
$cans = $rows['answer'];
$test = array($cans);
$ans = array();
foreach ($test as $correct){
$ans[] = $correct;
```

into this

```
echo $rows['answer'];
```

Then it will just simply print all the data like this: BCACABDDCB

If there is a way to get all the printed output at once then I can just use str_split to split them.

I really can't find an answer about this. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions and look up SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Agree with ceejayoz lookup PDO it takes a couple of hours or so to learn the transition but is secure from SQL injection.

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP no, it doesn't. String interpolation is bad.

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP read the top comment on this first.

Comment: Uhm guys just to let you know, for now I don't really care about sql injections and such coz this is just for a school finals and what I really want to know is how can I store each into elements other than element 0

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP It's [not required](http://codepad.org/noIEwmAx).

Comment: What is the point of that inner foreach loop? You're fetching a SINGLE value from your query result, forcing it to be an array, then looping on that single item array, and stuffing that single item into yet ANOTHER array. It's utterly pointless.

Comment: I'm just experimenting tho, coz I really don't know what to do to store them into an array within a for loop.

Comment: Well I figured out a solution on how to make it store into different elements in an array.

To make it to work as it is, I just replace my code for array into this:

    $ans[] = $rows['answer'];

To make it sure it works I output it using var_dump.

    array(10) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "D"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "A"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "A"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "B"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "C"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "C"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "D"
    [7]=>
    string(1) "C"
    [8]=>
    string(1) "B"
    [9]=>
    string(1) "B"
    }

Answer (score 0):

You're going about this the wrong way. Firstly, you don't even have a definite relationship between question/answer and ID. You should fix this.

FYI, you can make arrays in a GET/POST by using the `item[key]=value` syntax:

```
?answers[1]=B&answers[2]=C&answers[3]=A
```

And so on.

As for your PHP... Stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're horrid things to use nowadays (and personally, I'd fail any student who used them in one of my classes).

```
<?php

// PDO object
$db = new PDO("mysql:localhost;dbname=database", $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// vars from HTTP
$answers = $_REQUEST['answers'];

// default vars
$score = 0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id = :id limit 1";

// here, we prepare the query above.
$query = $db->prepare($query);

foreach ($answers as $id => $answer) {

    $query->execute(array(":id" => $id));

    // make sure you have mysqlnd installed or anything
    // involving php and mysql is a nightmare anyway.
    $row = $query->fetch();
    $expected = $row["answer"];

    if ($answer === $expected)
        $score++;
}
```

You can simplify this further, probably. Read up on prepared statements.

Comment: I did this but no luck to make it work out as I'm terribly a beginner when it comes to mysql.